# exporting a matrix to a text file in python

Tags: python, file

I have a list of lists(matrix) in python and I want to export it to a text file. the inner lists have 3 elements. my file would have 3 columns. in other word, the first column would have the first element of inner list, the 2nd column would have the 2nd element of inner lists and the 3rd column would have the 3rd elements. I tried to make it but all elements would be in a single column.
here is a small example:
input:

```
[['ENSG00000137288.5', 0.16721311, 0.13442624], ['ENSG00000116032.5', 0.094311371, 0.1444611], ['ENSG00000167578.12', 0.062894806, 0.10162043]]
```

output(which would be a text file):

```
ENSG00000137288.5  0.16721311  0.13442624
ENSG00000116032.5  0.094311371  0.1444611
ENSG00000167578.12  0.062894806  0.10162043
```

do you guys know how to do that?
thanks

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: file = open("file.txt", "w")     
write.file("\n".join(["".join(str(item)) for item in re]))

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way without using numpy, pandas or any other external package would be something like this:

```
data = [
    ['ENSG00000137288.5', 0.16721311, 0.13442624],
    ['ENSG00000116032.5', 0.094311371, 0.1444611],
    ['ENSG00000167578.12', 0.062894806, 0.10162043]
]

# builtin python functions
data_file = "\n".join([" ".join(map(lambda x: str(x),row)) for row in data])
print data_file
```

Comment: this code has the same problem as mine. if I open the resulting text file in excel, all columns would be in the same column

Comment: @user3925736 That's not a problem with the code, which is alright, that's a problem with the way you're importing in the excel, you should specify ' ' as separator. Also, you didn't mention anything about excel in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `csv.writer`:

```
import csv
your_data=[['ENSG00000137288.5', 0.16721311, 0.13442624], ['ENSG00000116032.5', 0.094311371, 0.1444611], ['ENSG00000167578.12', 0.062894806, 0.10162043]]
with open('output.txt', 'wb') as csvfile:
    w = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in your_data:
        w.writerow(row)
```

You can specify any delimiter you want (comma,tab,space etc.) and there can be any number of columns and rows in the matrix.

If you want to open the file in excel, then use comma `,` as delimeter and change file name to `.csv` :

```
import csv
your_data=[['ENSG00000137288.5', 0.16721311, 0.13442624], ['ENSG00000116032.5', 0.094311371, 0.1444611], ['ENSG00000167578.12', 0.062894806, 0.10162043]]
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    w = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in your_data:
        w.writerow(row)
```

or using `tab` with `dialect='excel'`:

```
import csv
your_data=[['ENSG00000137288.5', 0.16721311, 0.13442624], ['ENSG00000116032.5', 0.094311371, 0.1444611], ['ENSG00000167578.12', 0.062894806, 0.10162043]]
with open('output.xls', 'wb') as csvfile:
    w = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t', dialect='excel')
    for row in your_data:
        w.writerow(row)
```